# How to check the validity of the OpenAI key from python?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

- https://pypi.org/project/openai/

  > "The library needs to be configured with your account's secret key which
  > is available on the
  > [website](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys). [...] Set it as
  > the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable"

When I ask Chat GPT to complete a message

```
import openai
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "What are the trade-offs around deadwood in forests?"}]
)
print(response)
```

I get a `RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.`

Is there a python method to check that the key is valid?

```
In [35]: openai.api_key
Out[35]: 'sk-...'
```

Comment: The issue is that ChatGPT API is not included inside ChatGPT Plus: "Please note that the ChatGPT API is not included in the ChatGPT Plus subscription and are billed separately. The API has its own [pricing](https://openai.com/pricing) [...]. The ChatGPT Plus subscription covers usage on chat.openai.com only and costs $20/month." https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7039783-how-can-i-access-the-chatgpt-api

Answer (score 4):

To check if your OpenAI API key is valid, you can try making a test API call and see if it works without any errors. Here's a simple code example:

```py
import openai

openai.api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

def is_api_key_valid():
    try:
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="davinci",
            prompt="This is a test.",
            max_tokens=5
        )
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# Check the validity of the API key
api_key_valid = is_api_key_valid()
print("API key is valid:", api_key_valid)
```

Replace `'YOUR_API_KEY'` with your actual OpenAI API key. The `is_api_key_valid` function attempts a simple test API call. If the call succeeds without any errors, it means your API key is valid, and the function returns `True`. However, if any error occurs during the API call, it means the key is likely invalid, and the function returns `False`.

By running the code and checking the value of `api_key_valid`, you can determine if your OpenAI API key is valid.

Comment: Thanks. `response = openai.Completion.create(engine="davinci", prompt="Test")` returns `RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.`.

Comment: You probably need to buy OpenAI Tokens to use the API, but that error message means that your API key is valid after all

Comment: Did you generate this answer using an ai like ChatGPT?

Comment: No, I work building things with OpenAI, I have my own set of openai_utilts.py

Comment: This way of checking the API will consume credits. Is there any way to do it for free?

Comment: @AlejandroLozdziejski Best way to do it is following what Ajit Choudhary answered.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to check if the OpenAI API key is valid then you can use the **openai.Model.list()** function.

```
import openai

def check_openai_api_key(api_key):
    openai.api_key = api_key
    try:
        openai.Model.list()
    except openai.error.AuthenticationError as e:
        return False
    else:
        return True


api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
is_valid = check_openai_api_key(api_key)

if is_valid:
    print("Valid OpenAI API key.")
else:
    print("Invalid OpenAI API key.")
```

This code will check if the API key is valid by calling the openai.Model.list() function. If the API key is valid, then the function will return a list of all of the available OpenAI models. If the API key is invalid, then the function will raise an *openai.error.AuthenticationError* exception.

Answer (score 3):

The Python codes shown, accesses `openai.Model`, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0, see the [v1.0.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742#:%7E:text=Model.list()%20%2D%3E-,client.models.list(),-openai.Model.delete) or README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

Here is the adapted python code:

```py
import openai

def check_openai_api_key(api_key):
    client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=api_key)
    try:
        client.models.list()
    except openai.AuthenticationError:
        return False
    else:
        return True


OPENAI_API_KEY = "sk-7....."

if check_openai_api_key(OPENAI_API_KEY):
    print("Valid OpenAI API key.")
else:
    print("Invalid OpenAI API key.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check its validity for a specific model or for all models like that

- for a specific model use a url like that:
  https://api.openai.com/v1/models/gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct
- to check its validity for all models use this endpoint:
  https://api.openai.com/v1/models/

```
import requests

def is_openai_key_valid(openai_key):
    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/models/gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {openai_key}"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
    if "model" in data and "error" in data["model"]:
        return False
    return True
```

For more info: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication

Answer (score 0):

The two ways via curl and python below both work to theck the API.

```bash
./testopenai
```

**testopenai**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2023-06-21
if [ "$OPENAI_API_KEY" == "" ]
then
  echo "OPENAI_API_KEY env variable needs to be set to a key see https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys"
  echo "export OPENAI_API_KEY="
  exit 1
fi
if [ "$OPENAI_API_ORG" == "" ]
then
  echo "OPENAI_API_ORG env variable needs to be set  see https://platform.openai.com/account/org-settings"
  echo "export OPENAI_API_ORG="
  exit 1
fi

#
# test via curl
#
viacurl() {
    curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer [$OPENAI_API_KEY]" \
    -H "OpenAI-Organization: $OPENAI_API_ORG" \
      -d '{
      "model": "text-davinci-003",
      "prompt": "Hello World?",
      "max_tokens": 4000,
      "temperature": 1.0
    }' \
    --insecure
}

#
# test via python
#
viapython() {
  code="/tmp/testopenai.py"
cat << EOF > $code
import os
import openai
# https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
openai.organization = os.getenv('OPENAI_ORG')

# list models
models = openai.Model.list()

# print the first model's id
print(models.data[0].id)

# create a chat completion
chat_completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])

# print the chat completion
print(chat_completion.choices[0].message.content)
EOF
python $code
}

viacurl
viapython
```

Comment: see https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/494

Comment: The issue above was created by me when i still got 


openai.error.AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided: cmdftp@e******.com. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.
Due to a .netrc file

Answer (score 0):

To check if your OpenAI API key is valid, you can create a new function and see if it works without any errors. Here's a simple code example:

```
import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def check_openai_api_key(api_key):
    openai.api_key = api_key
    try:
        print(openai.Engine.list())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    else:
        return True

# Replace os.getenv("OPENAI_KEY") with your OpenAI API key.
# Or you can create a .env file and add OPENAI_KEY=your-api-key
api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_KEY") 
is_valid = check_openai_api_key(api_key)

if is_valid:
    print("Valid OpenAI API key.")
else:
    print("Invalid OpenAI API key.")
```